# Error in Hamiltonian of system in a paper

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, textbook-erratum

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6872) the authors investigate how work can be extracted from entanglement. However in section II under point 1. I think there is a mistake:
They write that the Hamiltonian is
$$H_i=H_i^A \otimes H_i^B \otimes H^M\!.$$
However if this acts on a ket then the energy of each subsystem would be multiplied instead of added.
Shouldn't it therefore be: $$H_i=H_i^A \otimes \mathbb{I}^B\otimes \mathbb{I}^M+\mathbb{I}^A \otimes H_i^B \otimes \mathbb{I}^M+\mathbb{I}^
A\otimes \mathbb{I}^B \otimes  H^M$$ such that the total energy adds up.
This seems like a rookie mistake and I am little perplexed, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: It just seems like a typo - I don't think they use that formula later.